# dependency for @Target Annotation in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I know its a very basic question but i didn't get any success from google. So the scenario is that i am working on spring security and for this i am trying to create an interface for email validation and add some annotations which are not working because their In-build class is missing or we can say that the dependency is missing.
the following annotations are :

`@Target({TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE}) 
 @Retention(RUNTIME)
 @Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
 @Documented`

which dependency should i inject in my pom.xml so that it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future Problem Inject these 3 dependencies and code works fine.

```
 <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
       </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you show refer Hibernate validator ? I guess

Comment: I have tried this dependency but it works for notnull,notempty and size annotations only not for the above four. https://stackoverflow.com/users/8017619/pain

Comment: Actually Hibernate Validator works i haven't noticed before thanks for the remainder.